# passing annotation argument without specifing name in java

Tags: java, annotations

Is there any way to pass annotation arguments like this :

`@MyAnnotation(4)`

instead of

`@MyAnnotation( value = 4)`

Answer (score 6):

yes if you define the annotation with reference name `value`

```
@interface MyAnno{
   String value();
}
```